# How to get the Amplitude of TTS

Tags: android, voice, audio, text-to-speech

I am trying to listen TTS voice amplitude and silence in between words. I will use this for showing some animations synchronized with the TTS voice

I could not find a way to make it work. Hope it is possible if I could convert TTS to sound file and read it, but not sure.

Please advice me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to synchronize the audio with visual actions, you'll have to set an [`TextToSpeech.OnUtteranceCompletedListener`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/tts/TextToSpeech.OnUtteranceCompletedListener.html) (or since ICS: an [`UtteranceProgressListener`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/tts/TextToSpeech.html#setOnUtteranceProgressListener%28android.speech.tts.UtteranceProgressListener%29)) to the TTS engine. That way you can determine when a specific piece of text has been synthesized.

Alternatively, you can synthesize the text to an audio file using the [`synthesizeToFile(String text, HashMap<String, String> params, String filename)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/tts/TextToSpeech.html#synthesizeToFile%28java.lang.String,%20java.util.HashMap%3Cjava.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%3E,%20java.lang.String%29) method.